# Accessing Swift code from Today Widget

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-today-widget

I have an app plus a today widget.
I have a big complex class, which is in my main app and is coded in Swift and I need to access it from Today Widget.
How can I import my main app Bridging header in Today Widget?
I tried `#import "My app-Swift.h"` but it's not resolvable in today widget.

Some day I should reference my ProductName in import statement, how can I find my exact main app product name?

Comment: Have you set the target membership of your class to both app and widget?

Comment: @vadian You are right! Please make it an answer so I can accept it as answer.

Comment: Done. Sometimes it's just a checkbox…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the target membership of your class is set to both app and widget